# How to keep the params the same across multiple state with AngularJS router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a search page with many different filters. Clicking on the filter would append it to the URL. Doing something like this:

```
var params = { color: blue, shape: circle};
$location.search(params);
```

There could be no filters, one filters, or a dozen. It just depends on what the user clicks. But when I change states, the url loses the params. None of the states other than the root has a url assigned to it. And it's hard to hardcode in what the url would look like because it totally depends on what filters the user clicks on.

Is there a way for the url/params to stay the same even when switching states?

Comment: store them using a service

Comment: Would that mean storing the params as a hash and calling         $location.search(params) each time I switch states? And is there a way to do that without manually calling it every time I switch states?

Comment: once you store them using factory, then call $location.search on $routeChangeStart event.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, $location.search(params) would keep your parameters intact across page changes...

How do you redirect to different routes?

If you use

```
<a href='someLocation'>
```

then your params will get overwritten. But if you use $location.path(...)

```
$scope.goToSomeLocation = function(){
    $location.path('/someLocation'); 
}

<a ng-click='goToSomeLocation()'>
```

then your params should remain intact.

As pointed out in the comments, you could save your parameters in a service as well:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.service('MyService', function () {
        var parameters= 'test';
        return { 
            getParameters: function(){ return parameters},
            setParameters: function(input){ parameters= input;}
        };
    });

    myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
        $scope.parameters= MyService.getParameters();
    });

    myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
        $scope.parameters= MyService.getParameters;
    });
```